# fog-google google-storage authentication fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-storage, carrierwave, google-authentication

I'm on rails 2.6.0 using carrierwaveUploader.
No matter what i do i can not authenticate with my google API for storage.
I've created the JSON key, the bucket, everything.

My configs are:

```rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: 'Google',
    google_storage_access_key_id: 'REDACTED',
    google_storage_secret_access_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nREDACTED\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

    # google_json_key_location: Rails.root.join('rails-app.json')
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'gomes-commerce'
end
```

I've tried to use `google_json_key_location` parameter as you can see, and give the path to the downloaded file as well... it doesn't work! 
it gives an error about required parameters `google_storage_access_key_id` && `google_storage_access_key`.

My (related) gems are:

```
gem 'fog', require: 'fog/google'
gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.11.1'
gem 'mime-types'
```

My output is always the same:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <Error>
        <Code>
          SignatureDoesNotMatch
         </Code>
        <Message>
          The request signature we calculated does not match the 
          signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing 
          method. 
        </Message>
        <StringToSign>
          PUT\n\nimage/jpeg\nWed, 13 Feb 2019 09:36:19 +0000\nx-goog-acl:public-read\n/gomes-commerce/uploads%2Fproduct%2Fimage%2F17%2Fscp_shirt.jpg
        </StringToSign>
   </Error>
```

I'm trying to figure this out for more than 48h now. 
I wouldn't come here & open a topic if there was any reference on SO that is working for my case.
Please help! :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. i haven't seen **any** references to this on SO so maybe i will help another aspiring rails developer like me.

If you want to use carrierwaveuploader (which is amazing).
My best advice is to combine this:

https://github.com/metaware/carrierwave-google-storage

Worked like a charm!!